# Very simple MWE, typescript error TS2322 (...) not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm working on a `React`/`typescript` project. I'm trying to wrap my head around error `TS2322` and solve it.

```
Type '{ submissionsArray: SubmissionProps[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SubmissionProps[] & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'submissionsArray' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SubmissionProps[] & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322
```

I've seen a lot of people have the problems, and solutions either don't apply to my context or are magic at play.

Here is the very short MWE

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react'

type Props = {
    name: string
}

const PropsSpan: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => <span>{props.name}</span>

const PropsComponent = () => {
    const p: Props = { name: 'George' }
    return <PropsSpan props={p}></PropsSpan>
}

export default PropsComponent
```

**What I tried**: a magical solution is to use {...p}, but I don't understand why, and it also requires additional instructions on the end of the functional component, if I was working with array of props.

**My Question**: how to solve this error ?

Comment: if you want to do that your props would have to look like: `type Props = {props:{name: string}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this, but it is definitely not the JSX way.

```js
import React, {ReactElement} from 'react';

interface ComponentProps {
    str: string;
}

const Component = (props: ComponentProps): ReactElement => {
    return <p>{props.str}</p>;
};



const App = (): ReactElement => {
    const props: ComponentProps = {
        str: 'hey',
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {React.createElement(Component, props)}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I recommend using the spread operator `...` like you told us about in the question and was proposed by [Phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120969/10315665).

You said you would not understand it so the quick explanation:

```js
const obj1 = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'};

const obj2 = {
    something: 'hello world',
    ...obj1,
};
console.log(obj2) -> {a: 'foo', b: 'bar', something: 'hello world'};
```

[Spread Syntax refference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

So in your case, it would populate the props much like:

```js
<Component
    prop1={<something>}
    prop2={<something>}
/>
```

And what you did was:

```js
<Component
   props={{prop1: <something>, props2: <something>}}
/>
```

The interface for that would have to look like:

```js
interface ComponentProps {
    props: {
        prop1: SomeType;
        prop2: SomeType;
   };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the props correctly. Props should be passed directly as attributes to the component like so:

```
const PropsComponent = () => {
    return <PropsSpan name="George"></PropsSpan>
}
```

If you want to create the props object first, and then pass it down as props to the `PropsSpan` component, you could use object destructuring instead, like so:

```
const PropsComponent = () => {
    const p: Props = { name: 'George' }
    return <PropsSpan {...p}></PropsSpan>
}
```

It gives the same effect as above, though it is not recommended.